# Google Guice binding issue

Tags: java, reflection

I'm using the Google Guice IoC container. I have two packages, one containing interfaces and one containing implementations for those interfaces.

The ClassFinder class returns a list of classes from a package.

When I try to **bind** the interface to an implementation, I receive the following compile error: Cannot resolve method to `<java.lang.Class<capture<?>>`from the **to** method.

The API specifies that to can take as a parameter Class and packageClass is Class. What should be the problem?

```
public void autoMatch(String basePackageName)
    {
        String interfacesPackage = basePackageName + "." + interfacesPackageName;
        String implementationPackage = basePackageName + "." + implementationPackageName;

        List<Class<?>> interfaces = ClassFinder.find(interfacesPackage);
        List<Class<?>> implementations = ClassFinder.find(implementationPackage);
        for(Class<?> packageClass : implementations)
        {
            String name = packageClass.getSimpleName();
            try
            {
               Class<?> foundInterface
                         = interfaces.stream()
                          .filter(packageInterface -> packageInterface.getSimpleName().equals(name + "Interface"))
                          .findFirst().get();
                bind(foundInterface).to(packageClass);
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException exception)
            {
                Log.error("IoC", "Could not match interface to implementation", exception);
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT

Managed to solve the issue by casting to (Class). The class is found, but it throws a java.lang.NullPointerException when binding.

Comment: Why are you doing it like this?

Comment: It's a easy way to create the bindings when I have many classes in a package and the scenario is 1 interface/1 implementation. If a special case arrives, it will be treated differently. What approach would you use? @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen

Comment: How many are many? I had to revisit my habits after switching from Guice to dagger.

Comment: At the moment they are not so many, but they may grow in the future as I add new new classes. Let's say 20-30 interface/implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you loose the information at *compile-time* the class implements the interface.  From the compilers point of view you end up with two unrelated `Class<?>` objects and as Guice is written with generics there is no method for binding them to each other.

Untested:  Consider using `Class` instead of `Class<?>` so generics are not used.

That said, I would suggest you write the 20-30 bindings out by hand.  The idea with Dependency Injection is to decouple interfaces from their implementation and your approach will introduce a subtle, hard to debug runtime dependency between them which I do not think is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue by no longer using ClassFinder to find the classes and by using the Reflections library.

```
public void autoMatch(String basePackageName)
{
    String interfacesPackage = basePackageName + "." + interfacesPackageName;
    String implementationPackage = basePackageName + "." + implementationPackageName;

    Reflections interfacesReflections = new Reflections(interfacesPackage);
    Reflections implementationsReflections = new Reflections(implementationPackage);

    Set<Class<? extends Object>> interfaces = interfacesReflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
    Set<Class<? extends Object>> implementations = implementationsReflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);

    for(Class<?> packageClass : implementations)
    {
        String name = packageClass.getSimpleName();
        try
        {
            Class<?> foundInterface
                    = interfaces.stream()
                      .filter(packageInterface -> packageInterface.getSimpleName().equals(name + "Interface"))
                      .findFirst().get();
            bind(foundInterface).to((Class)packageClass);
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException exception)
        {
            Log.error("IoC", "Could not match interface to implementation", exception);
        }
    }
}
```